# SQL Join Constraint Column on Another Joined Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So practically I have 3 tables:

**products**
id

**orders**
id
status

**order_items**
id
order_id
product_id
quantity

So I want to query by products table as the main one. I want to know how many each one has been ordered, hence

```
SELECT products.*, SUM(order_items.quantity) AS sale_count 
 FROM products 
 LEFT JOIN order_items ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
 GROUP BY products.id
```

Everything works fine, no problem. But this query will count any `order_items` for each row, now I want to count only if the order status is `done`. But the problem is to get the status of that `order_items` you need to reference `orders` right?

```
 SELECT products.*, SUM(order_items.quantity) AS sale_count 
 FROM products 
 LEFT JOIN order_items ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
 LEFT JOIN orders ON order_items.order_id = orders.id AND orders.status = 'done' 
 GROUP BY products.id
```

But this doesn't make a constraint on the order_items instead only order which has the status of `done` will be shown in the table else NULL.

How to approach this problem? Thank you for your kind help. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: just change your 2nd join to an inner join. `JOIN orders ON order_items.order_id = orders.id AND orders.status = 'done'` (Take out the `LEFT`)

Comment: small hint on data design naming.  typically tables are name singular not plural.  so "product", "order" and "order_item" would be more standard names.  they are named for the type of one row not the collection.  tales are always a collection.

Comment: yeah, that's what I used to do, it just Laravel Eloquent, wants the other way around, so you need the plural form for the table name.. I prefer everything to be singular to be honest, except for collection for easier foreach.

Comment: just a question, if I use INNER JOIN or JOIN in the second JOIN, it will only return rows that has been ordered right? I cannot query all products, because I still want the sale_count to return 0 well actually NULL, if the product has never been ordered.

Comment: that is correct, in your question I thought you said you only wanted items that had been ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear to me what you are asking, but I think you are asking how to count orders for which the order status is done without throwing out results for which the order status is not done. If so, then the following should work:

```
    SELECT products.*, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status = 'done' 
        THEN order_items.quantity 
        ELSE 0 END) AS sale_count 
    FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN order_items 
        ON products.id = order_items.product_id 
    LEFT JOIN orders 
        ON order_items.order_id = orders.id  
    GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, the problem is not only how many time it got ordered, but the item has quantity too in each order, and what I need is to SUM the whole quantity from every order, which has `status` = 'done', thanks for your reply, I'll get back to you soon

Comment: Hi @evanv, thank you for your answer, it works and I choose yours as best answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.status = 'done' THEN order_items.quantity END) AS sale_count
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON p.id = oi.product_id LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON oi.order_id = o.id 
GROUP BY p.id;
```

I moved the `'done'` condition to a `case` statement.  You can leave it in the `on` clause as well, if you like.  I just think this logic is more explicit about your intention.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff both your and @evanv answer works exactly as I wanted to be, the ON clause won't work though, because I tried it before. And it will instead return the row/columns from `orders` table and return NULL if the order is not 'done', but the quantity will still regard all orders. I had to choose the @evanv answer though because his is slightly better with ELSE 0, it return 0 instead NULL now for every sum, it works much better now henceforth. Although thank you for your answer as well :D